# mysql/php wrong logic with sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a project which has an ability of a user to approve or revoke application (like scholarship). But I can't seem to find out why it's not doing what I wanted to do. Please do check my code below:

```
$try = mysql_query("UPDATE new_applicants SET ApplicantStatusId='$status', DateManaged = NOW() WHERE ApplicantId='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$try1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($try);

$status1 = $try1["ApplicantStatusId"];

if( $status1 == 2 ){
header('location: ../employeepage.php');
exit();
}

else{

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO scholar_profile (Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Address, EmailAddress,  BirthDate, BirthPlace, Religion, Age, Gender, ContactNo, Skill, Talent, LevelId, GWA, CategoryId, StatusId, SchoolId, BarangayId) SELECT Firstname, Middlename, Lastname, Address, EmailAddress, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Religion, Age, Gender, ContactNo, Skill, Talent, LevelId, GWA, CategoryId, StatusId, SchoolId, BarangayId
FROM new_applicants
WHERE new_applicants.ApplicantId = '$id'" or die(mysql_error()); 

}
```

When the applicantstatus becomes 2 = revoked, it should not copy the data to scholar_profile. But when I tried this, it still copies. What's wrong with this? thanks.

Comment: [**Immediately stop using `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just change the `where` clause of the SQL statement:

```
WHERE new_applicants.ApplicantId = '$id' and new_Applicants.ApplicantStatusId <> 2"
```

Then you don't have to worry about the logic in php.

Answer (score 1):

You're updating a table, so `mysql_fetch_assoc` won't return anything. I.e. `$status1` will be `null`. If you want to select that data (ApplicantStatusID, ...) you'll have to use a `SELECT` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching `$try1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($try);` on an `UPDATE` statment
which is not true.

fetch is only with `SELECT` statment